# Method to change specific value inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Given a class with a multidimensional array as private property.

I'm trying to write a method `setValue()` which could change any value of this private array by passing:

- some kind of path to a specific value (*e.g. $path = ['lorem' => ['ipsum' => ['dolor' => ['sit' => null]]]];*)
- the new value

...

```
Class Tree {
    private $tree = array(
        'lorem' => array(
            'ipsum' => array(
                'dolor' => array(
                    'sit' => 'old value'
                )
            ),
            'amet' => array(
                'consetetur' => array(
                    'sadipscing' => 'another value'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    // setValue has to be a recursive function I guess
    public function setValue($path, $value) {
        // ???
    }

    public function getTree() {
        return $this->tree;
    }
}
```

Thanks to a comment of [Gabriel on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge-recursive.php#92195) I was able to find a working solution.

You can see my solution among the answers below.

What I actualy want to know: What are alternative approaches?

Comment: @yivi did I violate any rules?

Comment: 'I want' questions, are generally frowned upon.  If you can put in your efforts for the setValue function, with desired input/output and highlight where your function fails it will be welcomed.

Comment: @Progrock - I thought I could show my efforts by answering the question (which I mentioned inside the question... but that was removed by yivi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some recursive array built-in functions that may help you here:

```
<?php
class Tree
{
    private $tree = 
    [
        'foo' =>
            [
                'bar' => 'baz',
                'qux' => 'quux'
            ]
    ];

    public function replaceLeaf($key, $value) {
        array_walk_recursive(
            $this->tree, 
            function(&$item, $index) use ($key, $value) {
                if($key === $index)
                    $item = $value;
            }
        );
    }

    public function replace($value) {
        $this->tree = array_replace_recursive(
            $this->tree,
            $value
        );
    }

    public function getTree()
    {
        return $this->tree;
    }
}

$tree = new Tree;

$tree->replaceLeaf('bar', 'stool');
$tree->replace(
    ['foo' => ['qux' => 'quack']]
);
var_export($tree->getTree());
```

Output:

```
array (
    'foo' => 
    array (
      'bar' => 'stool',
      'qux' => 'quack',
    ),
  )
```

However looking at your original question targeting the array is likely an easier syntax, especially if you are only changing one attribute at a time.  You'd have to change the visibility of the array accordingly:

```
$tree->tree['foo']['qux'] = 'whatever';
```

Answer (score 1):

*With the decisive hint from [gabriel.sobrinho@gmail.com at www.php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge-recursive.php#92195)*

The method `rebuildTree` does the job. But it doesn't just change a value in `$this->tree`. It creates a new array.

```
Class Tree {
    private $tree = array(
        'lorem' => array(
            'ipsum' => array(
                'dolor' => array(
                    'sit' => 'old value'
                )
            ),
            'amet' => array(
                'consetetur' => array(
                    'sadipscing' => 'another value'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function setValue(array $path_and_value) {
        $this->tree = $this->rebuildTree($this->tree, $path_and_value);
    }

    public function getTree() {
        return $this->tree;
    }

    private function rebuildTree(array $arr, array $path_and_value) {
        foreach($path_and_value AS $key => $value) {
            if(
                is_array($value)
                && isset($arr[$key])
            ) {
                $arr[$key] = $this->rebuildTree($arr[$key], $value);
            }
            else {
                $arr[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $arr;
    }
}

$Tree = new Tree();

$path_and_value = array(
    'lorem' => array(
        'ipsum' => array(
            'dolor' => array(
                'sit' => 'new value'
            )
        )
    )
);

$Tree->setValue($path_and_value);

print_r($Tree->getTree());
// ['lorem' => ['ipsum' => ['dolor' => ['sit' => 'new value']]]]
```